# Check if string contains substring with specific order

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string:

```
var mystring = "HELLO-FRIEND"
```

How can I check if `mystring` does contain a letter followed by "-" that is followed by a letter? I need `true` if a match exists and `false` if not.

Comment: Did you try any regex?

Comment: Tried `/[A-Z]\-[A-Z]/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex with a lookahead:

```
/[a-zA-Z](?=-[a-zA-Z])/
```

`(?=-[a-zA-Z])` is positive lookahead that asserts true if we have a hyphen and alphabet at next position.

**Code:**

```js
var mystring = "HELLO-FRIEND"

var re = /[a-zA-Z](?=-[a-zA-Z])/

var result = re.test(mystring)

console.log(result);
//=> true
```